# Is there a way to check index/position in a two dimensional array? for java

Tags: java, arrays

If I construct a two dimensional array such as

```
Object[][] myArray = new Object[5][5];
```

and I used a for loop to traverse the array, is there a way to check if my current position is a certain index?

like

```
if(myArray[3][4]) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  If you are using a loop, then you already know your current position.

Comment: if you have 2 nested loops, with two indexes, then you know where you are... Your question is unclear....

Comment: Your "like" is not like what you mean.

Comment: would I be right to assume you ment a for-each loop and not a for loop ?

Comment: ...and time's up, this is now "not a real question." Another ask-and-run. *sigh*

Comment: You need to use for loop with 'loop counters' instead of for-each loops.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    Object[] row = myArray[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        Object o = row[j];
        foo(o);
        if(i == 3 && j == 4) bar(o);
    }
}
```

But why would you want to do that over just calling `bar(myArray[3][4])` after looping?